# Trigonometric Identities involving fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question is to simplify:

[image]

However, when I do that I end up with:

## $\frac{\cos\theta}{\frac{1}{\cos\theta}}$

Now, I don't know how to deal with these types of fractions. I have not encountered them before. I am also not sure how to google this problem, since I do not know if they have a name.

Any help is appreciated. Ta.

Comment: In general, $$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{ad}{bc}$$

Comment: @DarthGeek Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1)

It's the same as
$$\cos\theta\div\frac{1}{\cos\theta}.$$
So?

Approach 2)

You can multiply it by $\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}=1.$ Then, you'll have
$$\frac{\cos\theta}{\frac{1}{\cos\theta}}\cdot\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}=\frac{\cos\theta\cdot\cos\theta}{\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\cdot \cos\theta}=\frac{\cos^2\theta}{1}.$$

Comment: @Bethelomew: I added a bit. I hope it helps.

Comment: It most certainly did, thank you again !!

Comment: @Bethelomew: You are welcome, again.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try multiplying by $1$ as follows: $$\frac {\cos \alpha}{\sec \alpha}=\frac {\cos \alpha}{\sec \alpha}\cdot\frac {\cos \alpha}{\cos \alpha}= \frac {\cos \alpha\cdot\cos \alpha}{\sec \alpha\cdot\cos \alpha}=\dots$$

This is sometimes a useful way to untangle nested fractions (it can reduce the chance of confusion, particularly when writing exam answers)

Comment: Much thank for that explanation

Answer (score 1):

Googling "Dividing Fractions" just generates hits that show you how divide fractions by multiplying the numerator by the reciprocal of the denominator, but it doesn't show you why.

When we have a fraction of 2 fractions our goal is to make the denominator 1 without changing the value of the entire expression fraction. We do this by multiplying by a number divided by itself (i.e. multiply the expression by 1).

$$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\color{red}{\frac{c}{d}}}=\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}\cdot\frac{\frac{d}{c}}{\frac{d}{c}}=\frac{\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{d}{c}}{\frac{c}{d}\cdot\frac{d}{c}}=\frac{\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{d}{c}}{\frac{cd}{cd}}=\frac{\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{d}{c}}{1}=\frac{a}{b}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{d}{c}}$$
This explanation presupposes that your ok with the following proposition
$$\frac{p}{q}\cdot\frac{r}s{} = \frac{p\cdot r}{q\cdot s}\text{ or }\frac{pr}{qs}$$
Applying this principle to your problem we have
$$\frac{\cos\alpha}{\frac{1}{\cos\alpha}}=\frac{\frac{\cos\alpha}{1}}{\frac{1}{\cos\alpha}}=\frac{\frac{\cos\alpha}{1}}{\frac{1}{\cos\alpha}}\cdot\frac{\frac{\cos\alpha}{1}}{\frac{\cos\alpha}{1}}=\frac{\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{1}}{\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\alpha}}=\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{1}=\cos^2\alpha$$